# CC430F6137 UART problem when DC powered

Tags: uart, msp430

I have a problem with my system and I can't handle the problem.

The problem is that when I power the system with DC volt (3.3V) without debugging then I can't see anything on the receiver side (Arduino Uno as receiver.) However if I use the debugger [FET430 - UIF ] then I can see all of the characters on the receiver side.

This is my code:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include "cc430x613x.h"
#include <msp430.h>
#include <string.h>
void terminal_write();
void UART_open();
void UART_close();
void main(void) {

WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
//__delay_cycles( 2 * 1e7);
while(1)

{
    UART_open();
    printf("system working\r\n");
terminal_write("AT\r\n");

__delay_cycles(5000000);

//_bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE);
    UART_close();

}

}

void terminal_write(char *info)
{
unsigned int i;


unsigned int len = strlen(info) ; 
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{

UCA0TXBUF=info[i];
__delay_cycles(10000);

}
}

void UART_open(){
        P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6;
        //UART Settings
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST; 
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL0 ; // ACLK
        UCA0BR0=3;   //UCA0BR0 = 3 ; //32Khz / 9600 –>> 3 
        UCA0BR1=0;   //UCA0BR1=0; // BAUD 9600;     ( UCABR1 * 256 ) + UCABR0  = UCABRx    see "slau259e.pdf"

        UCA0MCTL=6 ; //  see "slau259e.pdf" page 602 //
        //UCA0MCTL =| BIT7 |  BIT6  | BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0 |
        //          |------- UCBRFx --------------|----UCBRSx----------|UCOS16|
        // for 9600 baudrate at 32kHz UCBRFx = 0 , UCBRSx = 3 , UCOS16 = 0
        //          |  0   | 0      | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 1    | 0    |
        //          0b00000110 = 0x06 = 6
        UCA0CTL1  &=~  UCSWRST;// 
        UCA0CTL1  |=   UCDORM;
}
void UART_close(){
    
    P1SEL &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
    UCA0CTL1  |=  UCSWRST;
    UCA0CTL1  &=~  UCDORM;
    
}
```

If I use DC power then the system consumption is about 450-550 uA. If I use the debugger then the DC power consumption is rises to about 4.8 mA. If I use only the debugger [powered with the debugger voltage without using any external DC supply] then the system can't handle the communication properly.

Comment: This does not sound like a software problem. Please show the schematic of your circuit.

Comment: I solved the problem. Problem was that ; Vdd connection of the Serial Port [UART connection]had been floating. This connection had to be tied with "reveiver"(in my case Uno) side's Vdd. Otherwise program can't handle the UART signals. Thank you for your attention.